# how to check/get the current session google account name

Tags: asp.net, vb.net, session, browser, google-account

I want to check whether any google/gmail account is logged in current session. if not just redirect to the log in page, else retrieve the  gmail id. is their any posibility to do like this?

**Updates**

Using `Google api v3` to connect with the calendar; am not able to creating connection if another google account is logged in in current session; so i need to check whether any google account is logged in the current session;if yes get the gmail id; if not then it will work fine

Comment: Do you use your own login system?

Comment: Using Google api v3 to connect with the calendar; am not able to creating event if another google account is logged in in current session